# I couldnt install packages in my ubuntu machine. Error log shows nvidia-dkms-460 is the source of the problem

Tags: apt, 20.04, dpkg, initramfs, dkms

The following appears in my terminal whenever I try to install a package in my system.

```
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
INFO:Enable nvidia
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/dell_latitude
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/lenovo_thinkpad
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/put_your_quirks_here
Removing old nvidia-460.39 DKMS files...

------------------------------
Deleting module version: 460.39
completely from the DKMS tree.
------------------------------
Done.
Loading new nvidia-460.39 DKMS files...
Building for 5.10.1-051001-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 5.10.1-051001-generic
ERROR (dkms apport): kernel package linux-headers-5.10.1-051001-generic is not s
upported
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.10.1-051001-generic (x86_
64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/460.39/build/make.log for more information.
dpkg: error processing package nvidia-dkms-460 (--configure):
 installed nvidia-dkms-460 package post-installation script subprocess returned 
error exit status 10
Setting up nvidia-driver-460 (460.39-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.136ubuntu6.4) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.10.1-051001-generic
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/tgl_huc_7.5.0.bin for module i91
5
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/tgl_huc_7.5.0.bin for module i91
5
Errors were encountered while processing:
 nvidia-dkms-460
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Everything was alright until i tried to update my firmware with Ubuntu's updater. Something went wrong and this happens since then.

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Remove any nvidia package with dpkg

Answer (score 0):

This error is more likely to be shown if you had a problem when you installed a package last time. To clear that run the following command.

`sudo apt --fix-broken install`

And then try to install the package that you were trying to.

(I know this is not the correct answer for this. But I don't have enough reputation to give a comment. So sorry if its wrong.)

Comment: No, I still get the same error message.